How long would world governments be able to cover up alien spacecraft during the cold war?
The time is December 1962, just a few months after the Cuban Missile Crisis put mankind on the edge of the Great Filter. America and the Soviet Union notice something strange from their telescopes and deduce that it is multiple (7) antimatter powered spacecraft each around the size of the Tokyo metropolitan area on their way to various Kuiper Belt objects, presumably with live extraterrestrial organisms aboard.
The spacecraft will arrive in the solar system around Christmas of 2001.
For how long would Earth's governments be able to cover up these spacecraft and say "Its a bunch of really big comets" or something like that before the civilian population finds out?
Edit 1: So I left out some details I think would be vital to answering the question:

the aliens' motivations for coming to the solar system are completely unknown
the spacecraft do transmit radio signals, but they seem to be incoherent (sounds like this https://youtu.be/psykUEmPEYQ )
the discovery of these spacecraft prompted research into objects beyond Neptune to try and explain the trajectory of these spacecraft, leading to the Kuiper belt being discovered earlier
the aliens are coming from the Trappist-1 system, Trappist-1 was also discovered earlier due to the spacecraft
Very few people know about the aliens, and these few people are some of the most powerful and educated in the world like the President of the United States, the head of the NKVD, the people at NASA who discovered the spacecraft, etc.


Could you clarify if we need to answer the title about visibility or the text mentioning how long they can cover it up? These are two different questions, making a 'single best answer' pretty difficult.

will change the title, yeah title is pretty vague

-1 for failing to research known government conspiracies to determine how long they lasted and then explaining to us why that research didn't solve your problem (see [ask]). VTC:Not About Worldbuilding per the [help/on-topic] because we don't help people tell stories.

understandable, thank you for pointing this out

due to you pointing this out, i will add further edits specifying how many people know this information

Early discovery of the star now known as Trappist-1 is incredibly unlikely, since the telescopes necessary (and the telescope technology necessary) for its discovery didn't exist until the 90s.  It is an incredibly dim dwarf star that has virtually no radio emissions.

even if it isn't registered as a star system, until the 90s it could just be referred to as "Origin Point" or something like that because I doubt 7 city sized spacecraft could just spontaneously appear and only later would it be registered as a star system

How would they know it was the origin point?  Even assuming they were able to resolve the spacecraft by their emissions, and assuming there were no trajectory changes between their origin and here, without any detectable star in the trajectory, it would just extend to infinity, rather than designating a point forty lightyears away as "origin point".

To be clear, the tech to determine that Trappist-1 had planets is a late 2010s-era issue.  Even seeing the star required 90s-era telescopes.  So there was no hint that there was anything there before the 90s MASS2 survey.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Minor detail - there was no NKVD in 1962 and hadn't been for 15 years, by that point it was already the KGB.

@user111403 that's what you think. In reality the KGB was merely to divert the attention of the West away from the NKVD, who started quietly investigating newly discovered alien spacecraft.

@FrançoisJurain Stalin's so-called "purges" were actually a cover-up for the Soviets transferring their best minds to deal with the alien threat. But now that I've told you, I'll have to kill you...


As pointed out by AlexP, forget about seeing the craft. But you might see (a) the antimatter engine exhaust and (b) occultations. The occultations are problematic because they work best to confirm a suspected course, not to find an object.
("1959, this star was blocked. 1961, that star. If we assume it is a powered object accelerating at 0.00-mumble m/s2, that means ..." -- "How about assuming two separate KBO in unpowered orbits?")
The radio signals would have to be recognized as non-natural. Consider the initial Little Green Men moinker for a pulsar.

So what you have is a twin problem:

How big is the conspiracy, and can it prevent leaks?
At first you had the US and the Soviets, NASA and the Soviet space program, probably making the detection on infrared and then correlating other parts of the spectrum. They follow what civilian astronomers do with large, expensive telescopes in their respective countries, and either co-opt them or shut their programs down. ("What do you mean, I cannot get any more telescope time?")
As technology improves, more and more countries have telescopes like that. The EC/EU, China, and so on. Those governments need to be included in the conspiracy. During the Cold War, NATO and the Warsaw Pact might have been helpful. ("Do not point your telescope at our strategic orbital infrastructure. Here is where you should not look.")
But then things happen. The US President has to resign, and people worried about him drinking. An ex-President went into mental decline. The Soviet Union crumbled. Was the Russian President alcoholic? So nobody of them blabbed?
SETI and all that.
With improvements in signals processing, the unintelligible signals might still be recognized as not natural. But you have the edge that the conspiracy started around the start of systematic SETI. Was that program co-opted? Say you have a bunch of papers out on fictional "micro-pulsars" which are only detectable through their patterned transmissions, and pawns or tools of the conspiracy write papers proposing and debunking natural explanations.
There will be a conspiracy fringe calling those "micro-pulsars" alien spacecraft, but not many reputable scientists will consider them. The proponents of the "alien theory" are pawns of the conspiracy, mostly tinfoil hat types sharing badly mimeographed papers with too many exclamation marks and uneven capitalization.
Relatively early, get a good movie director and some Hollywood stars to turn the fringe theory into a successful movie. From then on, reputable pawns say "yeah, sure, I've enjoyed the movie, too. But it was a movie, you know."

So when does it unravel?
With the internet, which allows much better communication of the fringe researchers to compare their notes. They are no longer rely on magazines which can be subverted by pawns of the conspiracy.

Plot twist
There is no telescope on Earth which can see a Tokyo-sized object outside the Kuiper belt. Not in 2024, and definitely not in 1962.
The Tokyo metropolitan area is about 13,000 km². Assuming that when saying that the objects are about the size of Tokyo metropolitan area the question really means that their cross-section is about that size, the diameter of the objects would be about 130 km. Even the Hubble space telescope has trouble seeing objects smaller than (with luck) 600 km across at the distance of Pluto, and much less farther out. As for ground-based telescopes, forget it.
Whatever those astronomers saw, it was not seven Tokyo-sized spacecraft.
I suggest that what the astronomers at Mount Palomar actually saw was a national security letter compelling them to keep their mouths shut and play ball. The CIA then let it float, very discreetly, that the secret ten-thousand-inch Greater Hale Telescope had seen seven unknown objects about 130 to 150 km across moving in formation beyond the orbit of Pluto; the intention was to scare the Soviets into thinking that the Americans had a super-duper-mega telescope capable of such an impossible achievement, and then spend untold billions of cash trying to built one themselves.
But it came to pass that Comrade First Secretary of the Communist Party of the Soviet Union Nikita Khrushchev was not as dumb as the Americans thought. When Comrade Chairman of the Committee for State Security Vladimir Semichastny brought the news that the undefatigable heroic Soviet spies had uncovered that American astronomers had seen seven unknown objects about 130 to 150 km across moving in formation beyond the orbit of Pluto, Comrade Khrushchev called the great Soviet Astronomer Comrade Professor Doctor Nikolai Barabashov, Hero of Socialist Labor, and asked him to provide an opinion.
Comrade Barabashov burst into laughter and explained that absent some spectacular advance in computing technology no ground-based telescope could ever be made with such level of performance. And that he would definitely had known if the Americans of anybody else was anywhere near such a breathtaking breakthrough in computational optics.
After sharing the traditional liter of Stolichnaya vodka with Comrade Barabashov and sending him on his way with a dire warning to keep his tongue still or else, Comrades Khrushchev and Semichastny decided to make this feeble capitalist attempt at deception a teaching moment at the world-famous Academy of Foreign Intelligence, of course taking full credit for unraveling it.
With time, the tall tale of the ten-thousand-inch American telescope became a shared joke with the intelligence communities of countries that actually had a respectable intelligence community. It even became a sort of shared shibboleth to test the worthiness of wannabe intelligence officers from third-rate countries; when meeting in social context with such an upclimber, an American, or Soviet, or Israeli, or French, or English respectable spymaster would mention the Greater Hale in passing. If the uppity third-worlder did not show he was in the know, the interview would be cut short because it was clear that he had not yet acquired the expect level of proficiency.
In the Soviet Union, the Seven Alien Ships became an often told joke, alongside the old chestnut about the Soviets painting the Moon red and the Americans retaliating by writing Coca-Cola across it in white letters.
The humorous secret was finally revealed to the public by a pseudonymous post on Worldbuilding StackExchange. Social media has ruined the world.

Well, that certainly took a few different turns, all of which I greatly appreciate. In context of the OP's story it would be even funnier if in 2029 more-powerful space telescopes reveal an actual formation fleet around Pluto, and then the intelligence communities will have to convince each other "no, I'm serious this time, we actually saw it, for real this time!".
